# Relationship between two types of partition functions

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

After downvoting my previous thread, here is a more detailed explanation of my question. For $s\in \mathbb{C},\Re(s)>1 $, consider:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-n^{-ks}}= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\rho(m)}{m^{ks}}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{p(j)}{n^{js}} $$
Where $\rho(m)$ is the [multiplicative partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) of the integer $m$. And $p(j)$ is the [additive partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the integer $j$. Based on the equation :
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\rho(m)}{m^{ks}}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{p(j)}{n^{js}} $$
What arithmetical relationship(s) can be drawn between $\rho(m)$ and $p(j)$? For instance, how can we write $\rho(m)$ in terms of $p(j)$?

Comment: $\rho(m)$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A001055 – have you looked at the many links given there? (Is there any reason to think that there is a way of writing $\rho(m)$ in terms of $p(j)$?)

Comment: I have! I'm interested in the arithmetical relationships between $\rho(m)$ and $p(j)$. Not necessarily an explicit formula to write the former in terms of the latter.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459063/relationship-between-two-types-of-partition-functions